# Angular Material mat-drawer in full height flex, content overflow auto

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular-router

Yesterday I faced a CSS issue which seems to be related to `mat-drawer` and Angulars `router-outlet`. I have got a fullpage flexbox with two children. A `mat-toolbar` at the top and a custom component `app-sidenav` at the bottom. This works fine and the app-sidenav fills the rest of the page since the flexbox is stretchy. Have a look at this simplified setting before continue:

```html
<div class="flex">
  <mat-toolbar></mat-toolbar>
  <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
</div>
```

The related css is

```css
.flex { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: stretch; }
mat-toolbar { flex: 0 0 auto; }
app-sidenav { flex: 1 1 0; }
```

In the **app-sidenav** component I now have the following template

```html
<mat-drawer-container>
  <mat-drawer></mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content>
    <main><router-outlet></router-outlet></main>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

And the related styles are

```css
mat-drawer-container, mat-drawer-content { display: block; height: 100%; }
main { height: 100%; overflow-y: auto; }
```

This works fine and the height is appropriate unless there is no content larger than the `app-sidenav` height. The scrollbar appears at the outer flexbox component and not at the `main`-tag. I also tested `!important` at the heights and also `100vh` but with no success. So how can I get the `overflow-y` at the main tag working?

I'm pretty sure that there is a simply trick, but I can't get it for know. Thanks for your help.
Cheers!

---

Edit:

I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-drawer-routeroutlet-and-flex) for this issue. When you navigate to the *ciao* component you see that the scrollbar appears at the document root and not in the main tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to @Sakkeer's working solution I found another way without hacking the position attribute but with usage of flex. Just add (not replace) the following css rules to the existing styles.

```css
app-sidenav { display: flex; }
mat-drawer-container { flex: 1 1 auto; }
```

Comment: This should get more upvotes. I tried many solutions but had no success. Did not think of trying to do flexbox like that.

Answer (score 4):

Try this for main css class

```
main { 
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will add two scrollbar. One for main page scroll and another scrollbar is for the mat-draw which slide from left. The mat-draw will have its own scroll bar. Just like the screenshot.

```
.mat-drawer.mat-drawer-end {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[image: mat-draw]

Beside having long page i can see the mat-draw on the top with its own scroll. I hope this helps with minimal code require to achieved what we want.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!add it to `style.scss`:

```
.mat-drawer-inner-container{ overflow: hidden !important; }
```

if it doesn't work for you, try below in `style.scss`:

```
 *{ overflow: hidden !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <mat-drawer-container autosize style="position: absolute;right: 0px;left: 0px;bottom: 0px;top: 0px;">
        <mat-drawer #drawer mode="side" class="toolbar">
            <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
        </mat-drawer>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </mat-drawer-container>
```

Above code just worked for me, when I put style directly and use autosize so that mat-drawer-container will not overlap on the router page.